# Merge multiple text files but skip first and last line of each file

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have a hundred of text files with the below structure:

```
file1.txt
Class Categeory_1 {
   (content 1, may contain many other block ending with }; )
};

file2.txt
Class Categeory_2 {
   (content 2, may contain many other block ending with }; )
};
```

I would like to merge all the files without the first and last line of each file, so the output.txt should be:

```
(content 1, may contain many other block ending with }; )
(content 2, may contain many other block ending with }; )
...
```

Files names are random, and class name are also random, but starting with "Category_"

I know how to merge all of the files together:

```
@echo off
    for /r %%i in (*.txt) do (
        if not %%~nxi == output.txt (
            copy /A output.txt+"%%i" && echo. >> output.txt
        )
    )
```

but not sure how to skip the first and last line of each file. Can you please provide some help, thank you.

Comment: Are you open to using utilities like `sed`?

Comment: Are the files 3-lines always?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working code sample

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if exist output.txt del output.txt
set "var="
for /r %%i in (*.txt) do (
  if "%%~nxi" NEQ "output.txt" (
  set "var="
  for /f "usebackq skip=1 delims=" %%b in ("%%~i") do (
    if "!var!" NEQ "" Echo !var!
    set var=%%b
))) >> output.txt
```

Here's a quick summary of what it does:

1. `Setlocal` allows the reference of updated variable values in the for-loop
2. Delete an existing `output` and reset `var` variable
3. `For` every text file, that is not `output.txt`

   1. Reset the value of `var` to nothing
   2. `For` every line in this text-file, skipping the first line:
   3. If `var` is not empty, `echo` its value
   4. `Set` the value of `var` to the current `line`

`>>` redirect all `echo`'s into `output.txt`

Note, the order of the last 2 steps is what allows you to skip the last line since you are always echoing the previous line.

- This means if the file only has 2 lines, it will not echo anything,
- If it has 3 lines it will only echo the middle one,
- And if it has 4 lines it will echo the middle two, etc.